# How to sum up for rowspan in table (element-ui)

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I know there is summary method for the table element. And my question, is there any possible method to implement the rowspan summary?

My idea is to rescan the tabledata, and insert the new data for the rowspan records: e.g. for the same id, I need to insert one new summary record. Thus, the tabledata should have 3 new summary reocrds

```
  tableData: [{
     id: '12987122',
     name: 'Tom',
     amount1: '234',
     amount2: '3.2',
     amount3: 10
   }, {
     id: '12987122',
     name: 'Tom',
     amount1: '165',
     amount2: '4.43',
     amount3: 12
   }, {
     id: '12987124',
     name: 'Tom',
     amount1: '324',
     amount2: '1.9',
     amount3: 9
   }, {
     id: '12987124',
     name: 'Tom',
     amount1: '621',
     amount2: '2.2',
     amount3: 17
   }, {
     id: '12987126',
     name: 'Tom',
     amount1: '539',
     amount2: '4.1',
     amount3: 15
   }],
```

after reset the tableData

```
  tableData: [{
     id: '12987122',
     name: 'Tom',
     amount1: '234',
     amount2: '3.2',
     amount3: 10
   }, {
     id: '12987122',
     name: 'Tom',
     amount1: '165',
     amount2: '4.43',
     amount3: 12
   }, {
     id: '12987122',
     name: 'summary',
     amount1: 'xxx',
     amount2: 'xxx',
     amount3: xxx
   }, {
     id: '12987124',
     name: 'Tom',
     amount1: '324',
     amount2: '1.9',
     amount3: 9
   }, {
     id: '12987124',
     name: 'Tom',
     amount1: '621',
     amount2: '2.2',
     amount3: 17
   }, {
     id: '12987124',
     name: 'summary',
     amount1: 'xxx',
     amount2: 'xxx',
     amount3: xxx
   }, {
     id: '12987126',
     name: 'Tom',
     amount1: '539',
     amount2: '4.1',
     amount3: 15
   }, {
     id: '12987126',
     name: 'Summary',
     amount1: 'xxx',
     amount2: 'xxx',
     amount3: xxx
   }],
```

I think maybe it is not a good solution. Any idea?
[image]
The expected results should have 3 new rows for summary
[image]

Comment: Do you want to sum up amount1 + amount2 + amount3 = amount4 in new col called summary for each Row

Comment: I want to sum up for each group which has the same col value ( e.g. here is ID) and the sum value should be shown in the table. It means sample above should have 3 new rows for '12987122',   '12987124', and '12987126'  and 1 new row for the total @bkwan